# How to pass hex codes to geom_hline in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-hline

In the code below I create a ggplot, `p1`, using data from `df1`. I would like to add a horizontal line at the `score` value for each item in `df2`, and colour each line using the corresponing hexcode for each item, contained in column `item_hexcode`.

I thought it would be straightforward to pass the hex codes to ggplot to determine the colour of each line, but I can't seem to work out how to. Every approach I try either throws an error or appears to treat the hex codes as strings/levels of a factor.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)
# create example dataframes
set.seed(123)
df1 <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = (sample(200:300, 5, replace = TRUE)/100))
df2 <- tibble(item = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "b"), 
              score = c(2.58, 2.63, 2.45, 2.13, 2.29), 
              item_hexcode = c("#DA020E", "#DA020E", "#034694", "#7CFC00", "#034694"))

# initial plot
p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + ylim(2, 3)
p1

# overlay horizontal lines on first plot, and colour lines according to hexcodes
p2 <- p1 + geom_hline(data = df2, aes(yintercept = score, 
             colour = item_hexcode), linetype = "dashed" ) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = df2$item_hexcode)

p2
```

[image: example_plot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for the function called `scale_color_identity`:

```
p2 <- p1 + geom_hline(data = df2, aes(yintercept = score, 
                                      colour = item_hexcode), 
                      linetype = "dashed" ) + 
  scale_color_identity()

p2
```

[image: The result]

This function is used when the values taken by the variable that you set for an aesthetic parameter can be directly used (here the values are hexadecimal codes that can be directly interpreted by `ggplot` as colors).

You would use `scale_color_manual` if you had levels in your variable (e.g. "low", "medium", "high"), and wanted to assign specific colors to them (and not the default ones, or colors from a palette).

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the helpful explanation too.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the somewhat unknown `I()` function directly in the call.

```
# overlay horizontal lines on first plot, and colour lines according to hexcodes
p1 + geom_hline(data = df2, 
                aes(yintercept = score, colour = I(item_hexcode)), 
                linetype = "dashed" 
    )
```

[image]

Comment: It was certainly unknown to me, at least. Looks like a surprisingly simple, helpful function though. Thanks!